# Extract few substrings from one string using a single regex

Tags: java, regex

As an input I get a string like "0123456789@site.com". All parts are variable. Only rules are that the number of digits in front is always 10 and then there is "@".
I need a regex which will allow me to extract "12345" (i.e. digits from positions 2 to 6) and "site.com" substrings. For example, in above case the result could be either "12345site.com" or "12345:site.com".
Can it be done with a single regular expression? 
How can we skip first digit and digits from positions 7 to 10 and '@'?
Examples in Java will be appreciated.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I use Java. But I thought it is not so important in the context of regex related question.

Comment: Absolutly not! Different languages use different regex flavors and implementations.

Comment: Ok. I added remark about Java.

Comment: Since the index and positions are known? Why do you still need a regex for this? Can substring not be used?

Comment: Yes, of course substring or other alternatives could be used. But consider this as a requirement to have a regex. Imagine that regex changes but the code which creates output string will remain. In case of playing with indices and positions I would need to change the code.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, this regex will do

```
\d(\d{5})\d{4}@(.+)
```

and then use

```
matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2)
```

to concatenate the groups.

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "0123456789@site.com";
    String patternString = "\\d(\\d{5})\\d{4}@(.+)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2));
        // shows "12345site.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that translate in Java to "\\d(\\d{5})\\d{4}@(.+)"? If so, then it results in one matching group "123456789@site.com"

Comment: Ok. Actually it works.  "123456789@site.com" was group(0).. There are also group(1) and group(2) with the right values.

Comment: How would you change the code if you don't know beforehand the number of matching groups?

Comment: You should always know the number of matching groups as soon as your patternString is final. If it's not, i would use "for" cycle to dash through them. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Ok. I can use groupCount() and iterate over all groups to concatenate all results.

Comment: How would you change the pattern if "site.com" would be an optional part? I tried to add ? to (.+) but still group count doesn't decrease and group(2) returns null...

Comment: If "site.com" is optional use "\\d(\\d{5})\\d{4}@(.*)" instead. ".*" means "nothing or some symbols". Just check all the groups for null in cycle. The number of groups never changes as soon as you don't change the patternString.

Comment: Ok. Clear. I was trying to avoid checking for null.. but since number of groups is predefined due to the pattern I will have to live with this. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for your input pattern:

`\d{1}(\d{5})\d*@(.*)`

```
2 capturing groups: 
   group 1: (\d{5})
   group 2: (.*)

Input: 0123456789@site.com
Output: 12345
        site.com
```

Comment: If in Java I try pattern = "\\d(\\d{5})\\d*@(.*)" then the output will be a complete input string

Comment: Yes. It works. I just should not use group(0). But rather group(1) and group(2).

Comment: @Max Okay. Initially you did not mention it's for use with Java. Glad you figured it out :)